# Printing console outputs on a JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

For example, when i call a function `connectToMyDatabase()`, i have few syso commands in it like

```
public void connectToMydatabase(){
 System.out.printl("trying to connect to db");
 /** other code goes here **/
 System.out.println("Connected successsfully"):


   }
```

Is it possible to print those system.out outputs on a jsp page.. ie the outputs getting displayed on the console need to be displayed on the jsp page as well.
When that function is called what all gets printed in the console should get displayed on the page as well. Is it possible ??

Comment: yeah.. its like creating a console on the jsp itself.. Its kinda challenging.. Even am working on it !

Comment: see my answer it may be something like that

Answer (score 2):

One Inadvisable way is write your output using this to a file

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("outputtest.txt"));
    System.setOut(out);
```

and then after the execution of the method immediately read the file and display the messages in jsp.

Answer (score 1):

In your Java program(servlet) set the attribute:

```
message = "Some text here";
System.out.println(message);
request.setAttribute("message",message);
```

Forward the request and response objects to the JSP page.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("file.jsp");
dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

Access it in your JSP page using the getter:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("message") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the message to the variable message, now return to the jsp. And do this,

```
<tr>"<%= request.getAttribute("message") %>"</tr>
```

Comment: What happens ? if he doesnt set them in the request ? will it be available

Comment: @sankrish I believe a getter and setter is enough.!! No need of setting it to a request. Struts ver 2+ will handle it.

Comment: Read the question . _When that function is called what all gets printed in the console should get displayed on the page as well. Is it possible ??_ he wants to print on the method execution

Comment: I don't think the real time console value must be set to the JSP. And that also can be shown in the same way. If the OP wants. All he want to do is a polling that will refresh the content.

Comment: I havent tried the way you say . will try and let you know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

JSP contains of java-codes(in the form of scriptlets) and the html content as both are rendered in the browser.

So once the method is executed in the java file . you can forward the message to the jsp file to check for the execution.

By setting them in the `request` or `session`.